# How to convert a text field to a date/time field in Access 2010?

Tags: sql, import, ms-access-2010

I am importing an excel file into Access 2010  and the date field(CALLDATE) comes in as text(YYYYMMDD).  I would like to use an update query to update a new field "dateofcall"  but using a date/time format. I tried to use:

```
UPDATE tbl_Import SET tbl_Import.dateofcall = CDate([tbl_Import].[CALLDATE]);
```

I thought it was going to be that simple but it shows up blank with a date format.  I also tried to use DateSerriel() but still was getting errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: first convert that `yyyymmdd` string to a proper `yyyy-mm-dd` string (e.g. add the dashes), then do an alter table to change the string field type to a date type. As long as the string **LOOKS** like a valid date, access will auto-convert the string to a real date value.

Comment: @remou: works fine in Access 2010 here. simple 1 string field table, two records: `2012-03-10` and `20120310`. change the field type to date/time, accept the warning message, and the 2012-03-10 is properly converted to a native `10/03/2012` (by my locale settings), and the 20120310 is nulled out for being invalid.

Comment: Here is what worked for me (a littel of both @Marc B and @Remou) I placed the below fomula in the update portion and it was accepted as a date.     `Format(Right([calldate],2) & "/" & Mid([calldate],5,2) & "/" & Left([calldate],4))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use left, right and mid string functions to construct a date from the various parts of the string.

For example:

```
DateSerial(Left(MyTextDate,4),Mid(MyTextDate,5,2),Right(MytextDate,2))
```

You can use the above in an Update query to update a date type coulmn 9field) to a the date from the text column.

Answer (score 0):

My date came in as text looking like this:"2013-03-23 00:00:00.0"

I take the left 10 characters only, "2013-03-23", this makes it so Access can recognize it is a date field and then I just switch around the format.

```
Format(Left([WEEKEND],10),"m/d/yyyy")
```