# Access Date Comparison Error

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am working on a sql statement where I'm trying to grab all projects less than or equal to the development date. However, I'm getting an error

"Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

I've searched and searched, but I haven't been able to find anything.

The raw results look similar to this:

```
| Title | devTerm | pilotTerm |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| Ex1   | 201401  | 201404    |
| Ex2   | 201301  | 201401    |
| Ex3   | 201504  | 201601    |
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE Len(devTerm)>0
AND Len(pilotTerm)>0
AND Date() >= CDate(DateSerial(Left(devTerm,4),Right(devTerm,2),1))
```

What am I doing wrong?

p.s. I wouldn't be using Access if I didn't have to.

I am referencing this article: [Convert Text to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359395/how-to-convert-a-text-field-to-a-date-time-field-in-access-2010)

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What data types are your columns?  If devTerm and pilotTerm are not text, that could be throwing the error.

Comment: They are both "shorttext"

Comment: @Ditto Why would they throw an error if they weren't text?  In my immediate window I have tested `MsgBox CDate(DateSerial(Left("201401", 4), Right("201401", 2), 1))` and `MsgBox CDate(DateSerial(Left(201401, 4), Right(201401, 2), 1))` both have worked.

Comment: @newd wasn't sure if it would implicitly convert them.   Chase: Why use CDATE to convert the return of DateSerial to a date? It's already a date?

Comment: @Ditto Yes good point, I just put that on there to try it out and I forgot to pull it off before I posted it.

Comment: @ChaseW can you try taking out the devTerm and pioletTerm conditions and see if you still get the same error? Just to simplify things down to the simplest form.

Comment: @Newd Yes I took out the two "Len(devTerm)>0 AND Len(pilotTerm)>0" conditions just barely and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: The error you're getting is pretty clear, and despite what Newd shows working in his environment, it's possible however you're running it is slightly different.  Try converting those strings to numbers before sending them into DateSerial:  ie  DateSerial(Cint(Left(devTerm,4)), ... )  ... not sure where else that message could be coming from.  ??

Comment: @Ditto definitely something worth trying.  Because for the life of me I can't spot any other possible places that could cause this error.

Comment: @Chase W Is this query being built in VBA or as an SQL query?   If it is directly in an SQL query can you post the exact query from SQL view, if it is in VBA can you `Debug.Print` your query string and post it?

Comment: @Newd Ok I've tried that too. I've converted it using CInt and then Val and still nothing.

Comment: @Newd This is build in Access as a SQL query. Yes I already posted the exact code from the SQL view.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the condition? `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE DateSerial(Left(fieldName, 4), Right(fieldName, 2), 1) <= Date()`

Comment: @Chase W Okay, and the last thing that I could possibly think is that you have one or more records that are causing the DataSerial thing to break. Directly in the table and sort A-Z on the devTerm field check for any blank or odd records, then sort Z-A and do the same thing.

Comment: @PaulFrancis Yes I just tried that again and it still didn't work...

Comment: @Newd alright so I sorted the column, there are quite a few blank cells, but that's why I included "Len(devTerm)>0". Thanks for your help

Comment: @ChaseW While I don't think I am a super SQL expert, I think it evaluates the other part of that query even if other parts fail.  I could be wrong but I think that all ANDs are evaluated.  Therefore even if you do `Len(devTerm)>0` then it is still going to try to evaluate the line causing the error.

Comment: @Newd I figured it out! See post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the issue. From the comments under my question, I was able to think about the Nz() function. The final query looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE Date() >= DateSerial(Left(Nz(devTerm, "1990"),4),Right(Nz(devTerm, "01"),2), 1)
AND Date() < DateSerial(Left(Nz(pilotTerm, "1990"),4),Right(Nz(pilotTerm, "01"),2), 1)
```

pilotTerm and devTerm were throwing NULLs out and that's where the issue was coming. I thought Access SQL would filter them out with

```
Len(devTerm)>0
AND Len(pilotTerm)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

So far the only way I have been able to recreate this issue is by making a quick test function to see what possibilities it could be.  From this I feel like there has to be a record that is blank or invalid, the function to recreated this is as follows:

```
Public Function Test()

    If Date >= DateSerial(Left("201401", 4), Right("201401", 2), 1) Then
        MsgBox DateSerial(Left("", 4), Right("", 2), 1)
    End If

End Function
```

It gets into the if statement, then breaks with type mismatch. So a blank record could likely be causing this or an invalid record.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is clearly the problem with `Left()` and `Right()` failing to return the right value because of **Null** values. You could use this,

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    projects
WHERE 
    DateSerial(Left(Nz([devTerm], 205812), 4), Right(Nz([devTerm], 205812), 2), 1) <= Date()
```

The Nz() will factor in the fact they are having Null values and creates a date way ahead in future which will always be GREATER than Date()